# Spring MVC processing queue events within a controller transaction

Tags: spring-mvc, transactions, message-queue

I'm using a transaction proxy to wrap a service, my applicationContext.xml contains:

```
<bean id="someService"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="target" ref="someServiceImpl" />
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="find*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
            <prop key="create*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean name="someServiceImpl" class="impl.serviceImpl">
    <property name="dataDao" ref="dataDao" />
    <property name="eventQ" ref="eventQJMSTemplate"></property>
</bean>
```

The queue artifacts are defined as:

```
<bean id="eventQJMSTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachingMsgConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="newEventQ" />
</bean> 

<bean id="cachingMsgConnectionFactory"  class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory" >
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="msgConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10"/>
</bean>

<bean id="msgConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" >
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
</bean>
```

The service has an operation

```
public void create(Object obj)
{
    dataDao.createAndSave(obj);
    eventQ.send(new NewMessageCreator(obj.getId());

}
```

The message handler is defined as

```
<bean id="newEventProcessor" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachingMsgConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="newEventQ"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="newEventListener" />
</bean> 

<bean id="newProjectEventListener" class="messages.NewEventHandler">
    <property name="dataDao" ref="dataDao" />
</bean>
```

The implementation of the message handler:

```
 public class NewEventHandler implements MessageListener
 {
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message)
{
    Long objId;
    if (message instanceof MapMessage)
    {
        try
        {
            MapMessage eventMsg = (MapMessage) message;
            objId = eventMsg.getLong("objectId");
        } 
        catch (JMSException ex)
        {
            log.error("Error parsing new event.", ex);
            throw new RuntimeException(ex); // TODO error handling
        }


            dataDao.find(objId);
            //ERROR 
            // This fails as the object is still in the save transaction

    }
}
 }
```

The get of the object fails, as the transaction hasn't completed.  What is the best way to have the mesage posted to the queue after the transaction completes?
I have to do it in the create method as that is the public interface into the service.

All components are running in a single tomcat instance.

Thankss

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a transaction which saves some data in database, and sends a message. And the receiver of the message tries to read the data from the database, but doesn't find it because the message is received but the sender's transaction hasn't been committed yet.

You are in a situation where you need a XA-capable (2 phase commit) transaction manager, which enrolls the database and the JMS broker into the same global transaction. This way, the writes to the database and the sending of the message are committed atomically, and there's no way to have a message sent if the database write hasn't been done yet, and has succeeded.

There are free such transaction managers, like Bitronix, Atomikos or JBoss TM.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  The initial way I was thinking of implementing this was to implement the message queue producer as an AOP aspect and add this to after the transaction has completed.

Comment: This has two drawbacks: it makes the code harder to understand (especially if the message content depends on what is done inside the method), and it doesn't handle the case where the commit in the database works, but the sending of the message fails. You lose the ACID features of the transaction.